# React Native - Get value from component - onPress

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I'm trying to get a value from a component that I have pressed but I could not pass it.

My **Welcome** class is using **Menu** component while this component has 4 **MenuItem** components.

Where it would be my problem? I couldn't get itemOnPress value into Welcome screen.

**Welcome:**

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {

menuItemOnPress = (item) => {
    console.log('ITEM', item);
};

render() {

    return (
        <Modal animationType={'fade'}
               transparent={true}
               visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
            <View style={styles.modal}>
                <Menu itemOnPress={(item) => this.menuItemOnPress(item)}/>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

**Menu:**

```
class Menu extends React.Component {

render() {
    const {closeOnPress, itemOnPress} = this.props;

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <MenuItem titleText={'XYZ'} onPress={itemOnPress(0)}/>
            <MenuItem titleText={'XYZ'} onPress={itemOnPress(1)}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your Menu component onPress functions to arrow function

```
class Menu extends React.Component {

render() {
    const {closeOnPress, itemOnPress} = this.props;

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <MenuItem titleText={'XYZ'} onPress={() => itemOnPress(0)}/>
            <MenuItem titleText={'XYZ'} onPress={() => itemOnPress(1)}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```